# Simple Past or Past Perfect - Sequence of Tenses

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past, sequence-of-tenses, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Could someone help me understand which tense (Simple Past or Past Perfect) would be more appropriate in the following examples, and why?

- I knew I asked the right person.
- I knew I had asked the right person.

Context: I asked somebody to help me with a task and now, several days later, I'm thanking them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In that link, the OP claims the past perfect in one of the  sentences is British English. That is simply bosh. I get so tired of some aspects of what people view as BrE and AmE.

Comment: @Lambie I largely reject the terms 'BrE' and 'AmE' as ill-defined. Along with 'standard English'; 'phrasal verb', 'non-count noun', 'intransitive verb' (you'll usually find at least the odd count /  transitive usage). And we're still arguing over agreed definitions for 'sentence', 'word', 'complement', 'subordinate clause', 'preposition' ....

Answer (score 0):

Tenses can sometimes get very tricky. This appears to be one such case. Attempting to bail you out of this 'tense morass'.

> I knew I asked the right person.

Your *knowing* and *asking* are simultaneous actions.

> I knew I had asked the right person.

This is what they call *pluperfect* in the English language.

Here two past events are involved: *your knowing* and *your asking the right person.*

In cases where two past actions are involved, one must precede the other (for otherwise we would need a different tense to describe the situation). Here *your asking the right person* precedes *your knowing* about it (maybe as an afterthought when everything went well).

Comment: And yet "I knew I had asked" sounds overcorrect. I am pretty sure most people use "I knew I asked the right person", regardless of the anteriority of the asking...

Comment: @fev _overcorrect_? Sheesh! I never knew the word could be used as an adjective too. *regardless of the anteriority of the asking*? I don't think that's entirely correct.

Comment: Despite my mistake, the meaning of my comment is clear. Thanks, wasn't aware "overcorrect" was only used as a verb. Must be my mother tongue that influenced me to use it that way.

Comment: This forum is where nitpicking is sorta allowed and perhaps even justified. Because ENGLISH ;)

Comment: Definitely. That's why I appreciate this site, you always learn...

Answer (score 0):

What @user405662 said is technically correct, but in practice, it is more common to say

> I knew I asked the right person.

For *[I knew I asked the right person](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20knew%20I%20asked%20the%20right%20person%22&biw=1536&bih=743&sxsrf=ALiCzsbual9_8uURMFJDpPFDE4GBLmVIOw%3A1662541621112&ei=NV8YY6m8BrCAhbIP-tuV8AE&ved=0ahUKEwjpqoCWqoL6AhUwQEEAHfptBR4Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22I%20knew%20I%20asked%20the%20right%20person%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjEK4CECc6CggjEK4CELADECc6BQgAEKIEOgcIABAeEKIESgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUK8HWN4dYIApaAFwAHgAgAFKiAGCApIBATSYAQCgAQHIAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)* Google finds around 45k results, compared to 20k for *[I knew I had asked the right person](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20knew%20I%20had%20asked%20the%20right%20person%22&biw=1536&bih=743&sxsrf=ALiCzsbhREIFQn1INat19NgSzQmIGCeo3Q%3A1662541937252&ei=cWAYY678DpaAhbIP8ue5kA4&ved=0ahUKEwju-N-sq4L6AhUWQEEAHfJzDuIQ4dUDCA8&oq=%22I%20knew%20I%20had%20asked%20the%20right%20person%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAwyBwgjEK4CECc6CggjEK4CELADECc6BQgAEKIEOgcIABAeEKIEOgQIIRAKSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUMcKWJwOYJwzaAFwAHgAgAFNiAGMApIBATSYAQCgAQHIAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz).*

And I suppose this is because the stress of the sentence falls on KNEW as in the common exclamation

> I ***knew*** it!

The purpose of the sentence is not to place the actions of the verbs in time, but to express the certainty of one's own good instinct.

*I knew I had asked the right person* is more often found not as an exclamation, but as part of an account of past events:

> I knew I ***had*** asked the right person when Nick quickly grabbed my hand and said... (*[From the Mouths of Babes](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2766256/1/From-the-Mouths-of-Babes)*)